# Basic route information with Cloudmade

Tags: iphone, objective-c, maps, cloudmade

I am trying to use CloudMade's route-me service in my application. All I need from the service is driving distance between two locations, I don't want to display it in a map.

There doesn't seem to be any tutorial in CloudMade's website that handles this. I mailed to the support address they have provided. Nothing back from them so far. Any help from people who done this before would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I lost hope with this one, and asked for an alternate option, and found a good solution with CloudMade after all.

[Calculating driving distance in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105875/calculating-driving-distance-in-iphone)